# 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am a beginner to Typescript. To begin with I have created "types.ts" and referred in index.html file. And I have installed typescript globally using
 `npm install -g typescript` in **Visual studio Code terminal window.**

After installation when I tried to use `tsc -v` , It gives me the error

```
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I searched and tried different options. I was adding following path as a environment variable.

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd

Then I restarted the machine still it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer my self. You can watch the below URL to understand the initial steps of configuration.

[Typescript Configuration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs6XWwQUs_A)

But the Error which i got is resolved by adding 
`%APPDATA%\npm` to my environment variable section.